Auditing for SSH jumphost and socks proxy
Problem:
For tech support activities, technicians must log into customer systems using customer-provided credentials, but we need to record which technician connected to which system for security and ISO compliance.
Current setup:
I've set up ssh bastion hosts (Debian 12) for such customer support activities.
We enforce access to customer systems through the bastion(s); each technician has one account on the bastion and authenticates via ssh keys.
The bastion is used both for ssh and web access to customer systems.
SSH access is performed through the SSH jump facility (ssh -J), and web access is performed through SSH SOCKS5 proxying.
We need to log each outbound TCP connection from the bastion with at least the username of the technician initiating the connection, the target IP address, and the port.
We've gone audited, logs are ingested into a SIEM through RSyslog.
The current working setup uses a simple audited configuration to log connections:
auditctl -a always, exit -S connect -F success=1

For some reason that I don't yet understand, when a user initiates a connection to a customer system using the bastion as a jumphost, a DNS query is logged (with correct user attribution) but not the actual connection to the target host.
Here is what I get in the auditde logs:
Aug 20 15:26:09 bastion1 audisp-syslog: type=SYSCALL msg=audit(**1724167569.113:16994887**): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=yes exit=0 a0=b a1=7f49a2dfa454 a2=10 a3=7ffe86122474 items=0 ppid=3840918 pid=3840929 auid=1002 uid=1002 gid=1002 euid=1002 suid=1002 fsuid=1002 egid=1002 sgid=1002 fsgid=1002 tty=(none) ses=5005 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" subj=unconfined key=(null) ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=connect AUID="firstname-lastname" UID="firstname-lastname" GID="firstname-lastname" EUID="firstname-lastname" SUID="firstname-lastname" FSUID="firstname-lastname" EGID="firstname-lastname" SGID="firstname-lastname" FSGID="firstname-lastname"
Aug 20 15:26:09 bastion1 audisp-syslog: type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(**1724167569.113:16994887**): saddr=02000035080808080000000000000000 SADDR={ saddr_fam=inet **laddr=8.8.8.8 lport=53** }
Aug 20 15:26:09 bastion1 audisp-syslog: type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(**1724167569.113:16994887**): proctitle=737368643A20726F646F6C666F2D73616363616E69205B707269765D
Aug 20 15:26:09 bastion1 audisp-syslog: type=EOE msg=audit(**1724167569.113:16994887**):

This DNS query is logged, but there is no log about the actual SSH connection.
In regard to SOCKS proxying, auditd does not seem to be able to provide the logs we need, outbound connections seem to be initiated by the sshd user.
Any suggestions about how to solve this problem?
Thanks


auditctl -a always,exit -S connect -F success=1


I couldn't figure out why this doesn't work. I suspect it has something to do either with sshd using non-blocking sockets (where connect() never returns success, only -EINPROGRESS).
So it might be easier to use firewall logging, with iptables -j LOG --log-uid which will include the socket UID in each message, or similarly nftables log flag skuid. This has a major advantage in that it doesn't depend on how the connection is made (blocking socket or non-blocking; 32-bit syscall or 64-bit syscall or io_uring).
Alternatively: Run your sshd at LogLevel DEBUG1 as then it will itself write the connection details to syslog:
sshd-session[1213015]: Authorized to grawity, krb5 principal grawity@EXAMPLE.COM (krb5_kuserok)
sshd-session[1213015]: Accepted gssapi-with-mic for grawity from 10.147.21.6 port 47240 ssh2: grawity@EXAMPLE.COM
sshd-session[1213015]: User child is on pid 1213018
sshd-session[1213018]: debug1: server_request_direct_tcpip: originator 127.0.0.1 port 65535, target ember.sym port 22
sshd-session[1213018]: debug1: connect_next: start for host ember.example.com ([10.147.1.4]:22)
sshd-session[1213018]: debug1: connect_next: connect host ember.example.com ([10.147.1.4]:22) in progress, fd=6

If your syslog daemon supports it, the UID of the sshd process could be added directly to the debug1 messages to get everything in one line.

The bastion is used both for ssh and web access to customer systems. SSH access is performed through the SSH jump facility (ssh -J), web access is performed through SSH SOCKS5 proxying.

These are exactly the same thing. They only differ in client-side handling, but the server sees both as the same type of direct-tcpip channel requests and they are handled in the same process via the same code. (Yes, it's the client that pretends to be a SOCKS5 server.)

In regard to SOCKS proxying, auditd does not seem to be able to provide the logs we need, outbound connections seem to be initiated by the sshd user.

This cannot be the case, as sshd is usually strict about isolating its session processes – once you've authenticated, the entire connection is handed over to a session process that runs under your account and that's what handles both the shell channels and the TCP channels. Having a user-controlled process run under the shared 'sshd' account would be very unusual to see.

Thanks for the useful response.
With auditctl -a always,exit -S connect (without the -F success=1) I can log non-blocking sockets and apparently now I have all I need.
